# Primefaces 3.4: Setting up a theme

Tags: primefaces

I'm new to primefaces.I want to set up a theme that i dowloaded from the primefaces site. I added this code to web.xml

```xml
<context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
    <param-value>casablanca</param-value>
</context-param>
```

and i put the casablanca.jar in the /web-inf/ directory but still doesn't work

Comment: It should be enough. Did you clear your browser's cache?

Comment: i did like you say and now i got another error:
javax.faces.FacesException: Error loading theme, cannot find "theme.css" resource of "primefaces-casablanca" library

Comment: Shouldn't it be in `WEB-INF/lib` instead of `WEB-INF` ?